# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to integrate Spring Security in my extjs project,but encountered the following error.
The entire stacktrace is.

```
 SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
at           org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1056)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:217)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:145)
at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:179)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:250)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:368)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4211)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4837)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1028)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:773)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1028)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:278)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:429)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:662)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:592)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:418)
    Apr 30, 2012 1:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Error filterStart
```

My web.xml is as follows

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate</display-name>

<filter>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


 <listener>
 <listener-  class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener- class>
 </listener>


<servlet>
<servlet-name>extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
     </param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**applicationContext.xml is**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
<!-- Annotated controller beans may be defined explicitly, using a standard Spring bean definition in the 
dispatcher's context. However, the @Controller stereotype also allows for autodetection, aligned with Spring 2.5's 
general support for detecting component classes in the classpath and auto-registering bean definitions for them. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.loiane" />

<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- misc -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Configures Hibernate - Database Config -->
<import resource="db-config.xml" />
```

**applicationContext-security.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd">

<security:global-method-security />
<security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.action" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>

<bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.loiane.security.MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <security:custom-filter position="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER" />
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.jsp" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" />

<bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/index.jsp" />
    <property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
</bean>

<!--
Usernames/Passwords are
    rod/koala
    dianne/emu
    scott/wombat
    peter/opal
These passwords are from spring security app example    
-->
<security:authentication-provider>
    <security:password-encoder hash="md5"/>
    <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="options" password="22b5c9accc6e1ba628cedc63a72d57f8" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:user-service>
</security:authentication-provider>
 </beans>
```

I have referred other threads but with no solution.
Can someone correct me where is the problem in the configuration?

Thanks for the time.

EDIT:
A new issue is with mapping.
Here is my controller class.I have my web.xml above.I am using **SPring Security**.
I am not able to navigate to the main.jsp after successful login.I have added the **@RequestMapping annotation** above the method.

Controller Class

```
      @Controller
```

public class ContactController extends MultiActionController  {

```
private ContactService contactService;

@RequestMapping(value="/contact/main.action")
public ModelAndView main(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    return new ModelAndView("main.jsp");

}

@RequestMapping(value="/contact/view.action")
public @ResponseBody Map<String,? extends Object> view() throws Exception {

    try{

        List<Contact> contacts = contactService.getContactList();

        return getMap(contacts);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return getModelMapError("Error retrieving Contacts from database.");
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value="/contact/create.action")
public @ResponseBody Map<String,? extends Object> create(@RequestParam Object data) throws Exception {

    try{
        List<Contact> contacts = contactService.create(data);

        return getMap(contacts);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return getModelMapError("Error trying to create contact.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you have all your dependencies in the build path. Try to remove your contextConfigLocation from inside the servlet definition, and declare it as a context-param, like they do in this example: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html

Comment: @Dani Thanks,I resolved it.But I have another issue now.`WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate/main.action] in DispatcherServlet with name 'extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate'` Could you please suggest me in the mapping where I am wrong? I have added my controller in the question as a edit.Any pointers to a good tutorial explaining **Spring Security** would also be helpful.Thank you very much.

Comment: That's because you actually don't have a mapping for /extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate/main.action. What you are mapping in that controller is, for example: /extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate/contact/main.action. So if you need to access the first URI you should remove "contact" from the controller and only map it with "/main.action". For Spring Security, the best tutorial I can recommend are in Spring books: Spring Recipes and Spring Security 3.

Comment: @Dani Ohh..that was stupid.Resolved it thanks once again.But can you suggest any online tutorials apart from the docs?Books atleast immediately I can't refer apart from a Ecopy if its free. :P

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure that this tutorial is useful http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html. But if you really want to learn about spring security i strongly recommend you the book.

Comment: @Dani Downloaded an ebook!! :) Will get a book for sure!!Thanks for the link and the inputs.Can you add your comment as answer so that I can close the thread as answered??I am not sure if it can be done for a comment.

Comment: @KillABug "Thanks,I resolved it" , can you suggest How did you resolve it ? I have been stuck on the same problem from the past couple of days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the issue with the controller: you actually don't have a mapping for
`/extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate/main.action`

What you are mapping in that controller is, for example:
`/extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate/contact/main.action`

If you need to access the first URI you should remove "`contact`" from the controller and only map it with "`/main.action`".

About Spring Security, I'm sure that this [tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html) is useful (or almost any that you can find googling), but if you really want to learn about it, I strongly recommend the Spring books: Spring recipes and Spring Security 3.

Comment: Link seems unavailable and/or redirects to creating spring project. any alternative ?

Answer (score 4):

try instead of:

```
 <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
 </param-value>
```

to do the following in /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml:

```
<import resource="applicationContext-security.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same issue. I tried  security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"

Remove criteria on pattern, my problem has been solved. Spring security itself append /spring_security_login url and provide it's login page.

Try it...

Comment: The issue was resolved earlier and I had accepted an answer then.I believe your may help others running into the issue.Thank you for the response