# JSF 2.0 + Spring 3.2 Security

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I'am trying to run my first Spring Security project with JSF pages, but i got stuck at the beginning.
My application looks like this:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

<display-name>SpringWebApp</display-name>

<!-- JSF Mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="8-25" queue-capacity="100" />
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10" />
<task:annotation-driven />

<bean scope="singleton" id="userBean" class="cz.web.ejb.UserTestScheduleBean">
    <property name="ts" ref="scheduler"/>
</bean>


</beans>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
          version="2.1">

<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>userTestManagedBeans</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>cz.web.managedBeans.UserTestManagedBeans</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>ejb</property-name>
        <value>#{userBean}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

When I Start an application, i got exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:549)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1096)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:663)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1468)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1447)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:862)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:358)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The only bean springSecurityFilterChain is Filter in web.xml, but i want to use the filter from web.xml, not the bean named springSecurityFilterChain. I tried to create bean like a filter and comment the filter in web.xml, but then i got exception i did not have filter defined. When i have defined both, i got OutOfMemory Exception because then have been in infinitive loop.

If I delete this part

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Everything is fine.

Please help. I got stuck on this almost two nights and i cannot find the bug.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a security configuration.

You may update your `applicationContext.xml` to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="8-25" queue-capacity="100" />
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10" />
<task:annotation-driven />

<bean scope="singleton" id="userBean" class="cz.web.ejb.UserTestScheduleBean">
    <property name="ts" ref="scheduler"/>
</bean>

  <sec:http auto-config='true'>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  </sec:http>
 <sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider>
      <sec:user-service>
        <sec:user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <sec:user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
      </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
  </sec:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

This basically auto-configures spring-security with a form-login and the example users.

Check especially for the `xmlns` declarations...

You may need to add the dependency for the `spring-security-config`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>yourVersion</version>
</dependency>
```

You can read about the `Spring Security Filter Chain Configuration` in the spring documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html).

See also:

- [What's the point of Spring MVC's DelegatingFilterProxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725234/whats-the-point-of-spring-mvcs-delegatingfilterproxy)
- [Rest basic authentication via spring security without form-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220971/rest-basic-authentication-via-spring-security-without-form-login)
- [what is the use of auto-config=true in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609655/what-is-the-use-of-auto-config-true-in-spring-security)
- [Getting error org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090890/getting-error-org-springframework-beans-factory-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-n)
- [org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380228/org-springframework-beans-factory-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-no-bean-named)
- [Spring security configuration error /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml and there's no bean called springSecurityFilterChain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270635/spring-security-configuration-error-web-inf-applicationcontext-xml-and-theres)
- [No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined - Spring Security 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132675/no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined-spring-security-3-1)